# Print only unique element from a list in scala

Tags: scala

Consider the following list(1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5) I want to print only  3. Since it is the unique one. Can someone help me with the Scala code.

Comment: What have you tried? why it didn't work? what is the relationship at all with **Spark**?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Spark question, but this function would do it for Scala

```scala
def uniqueElems[T](lst: Seq[T]) = { 
  lst.groupBy(identity).collect { case v if v._2.length == 1 => v._2.head }
}
```

Comment: why unnacessarily add generic parameters to answer a beginner question ?